# Getting Error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 (Request Entity Too Large) on ajax upload

Tags: php, ajax, apache

I am getting following error while trying to upload file with size more than 1 MB

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 413 (Request Entity Too Large) on ajax upload

Live Link : http://d.5me.net

Please help How can i resolve this?

Edit

PHPINFO: http://5me.net/phpinfo.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: By increasing the limits your server has configured for uploads.

Comment: Which server? Apache or Nginx?

Comment: Apache Server, I have tried all the suggestions in relvant questions already asked but no help

Answer (score 6):

If you're using nginx:

set `client_max_body_size XXm;` in your http, server, or location context.

Answer (score 0):

Increase MAX_FILE_UPLOAD in php.ini on your server.